# How to solve this multivariable recursion?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

How to solve this multivariate recursion?:

$$a(m, n, k) = 2a(m-1, n-1, k-1) + a(m-1, n-1, k) + a(m-1, n, k-1) + a(m, n-1, k-1)$$

where $m, n, k$ are positive integers.

Edit:

$a(0,0,0) = a(1,0,0) = a(0,1,0) = a(0,0,1) = 1$

$a(m,0,0) = a(0,m,0) = a(0,0,m) = 0, m > 1$

$a(m,n,k) = a(m,k,n) = a(n,m,k) = a(n,k,m) = a(k,m,n) = a(k,n,m)$

Comment: What are the initial values? Have you tried generating functions?

Comment: You need base cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the recursive multivariate function $a(m,n,k)$, we can define the generating function:

$$\Phi(x,y,z)=\sum_{m,n,k}a(m,n,k) \cdot x^m y^n z^k$$

Using the initial values above, we can define $a(m,n,k)$ as follows:

$$a(m, n, k) = 2a(m-1, n-1, k-1) + a(m-1, n-1, k) + a(m-1, n, k-1) + a(m, n-1, k-1) + [m=n=k=0] + [m=n=0 \wedge k=1] + [m=k=0 \wedge n=1] + [n=k=0 \wedge m=1]$$

Actually, I believe there are still some initial conditions missing, since for example $a(0,1,1)$ is not well defined. Computing its value will result in negative arguments: $a(0,1,1) = 2a(-1, 0, 0) + a(-1, 0, 1) + a(-1, 1, 0) + a(0, 0, 0) = 2a(-1, 0, 0) + 2a(-1, 0, 1) + 1$.

Adding the extra condition that $a(m,n,k)=0$ for any negative argument(s) solves the issue.

Let's move forward and substitute the definition of $a(m,n,k)$ into the generating function:

\begin{align}
\Phi(x,y,z)
&=\sum_{m,n,k}a(m,n,k) \cdot x^m y^n z^k \\
&= 2\sum_{m,n,k}a(m,n,k) \cdot x^{m+1} y^{n+1} z^{k+1} + \sum_{m,n,k}a(m,n,k) \cdot x^{m+1} y^{n+1} z^k + \sum_{m,n,k}a(m,n,k) \cdot x^{m+1} y^n z^{k+1}+\sum_{m,n,k}a(m,n,k) \cdot x^m y^{n+1} z^{k+1} + 1 + x + y + z \\
&= 2\Phi(x,y,z) \cdot x y z + \Phi(x,y,z)\cdot x y + \Phi(x,y,z) \cdot x z + \Phi(x,y,z) \cdot y z + 1 + x + y + z \\
&= \Phi(x,y,z)\left(2 x y z + x y + x z + y z\right) + 1 + x + y + z
\end{align}

After a trivial transformation we can get the generating function for $a(m,n,k)$:
$$ \Phi(x,y,z) = \frac{1 + x + y + z}{1-2 x y z - x y - x z - y z}$$

for the next steps we will use the following well-known formulas:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-\rho} &= \sum_i \rho^i \\
(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)^N &= \sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4=N}\binom{N} {k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}x_3^{k_3}x_4^{k_4} \\
\binom{N}{k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4}&=\frac{N!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!k_4!}
\end{align}

Applying them, we get:

\begin{align}
\Phi(x,y,z) 
&= \frac{1 + x + y + z}{1-2 x y z - x y - x z - y z} \\
&= (1 + x + y + z) \sum_{N}(2 x y z + x y + x z + y z)^N \\
&= (1 + x + y + z) \sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4=N} \binom{N} {k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4} (2 x y z)^{k_1} \cdot (x y)^{k_2} \cdot (x z)^{k_3} \cdot (y z)^{k_4}  \\
&= (1 + x + y + z) \sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4=N} \binom{N} {k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4} 2^{k_1} x^{k_1+k_2+k_3} y^{k_1+k_2+k_4} z^{k_1+k_3+k_4} \\
&= (1 + x + y + z) \sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3\leq N} \binom{N} {k_1,k_2,k_3,N-k_1-k_2-k_3} 2^{k_1} x^{k_1+k_2+k_3} y^{N-k_3} z^{N-k_2}
\end{align}

From the last expression, it is not hard to get the formula for $a(m,n,k)$, which by the definition of $\Phi(x,y,z)$, equals to the coefficient for $x^m y^n z^k$:
\begin{align}
a(m,n,k) 
&= \sum_{\max(m,n,k)\leq N\leq   \frac{1}{2}(m+n+k)}   \binom{N}{m+n+k-2N,N-m,N-n,N-k} 2^{m+n+k-2N} \\
&+ \sum_{\max(m-1,n,k)\leq N\leq \frac{1}{2}(m+n+k-1)} \binom{N}{m+n+k-2N-1,N-m,N-n,N-k+1} 2^{m+n+k-2N-1} \\
&+ \sum_{\max(m,n-1,k)\leq N\leq \frac{1}{2}(m+n+k-1)} \binom{N}{m+n+k-2N-1,N-m+1,N-n,N-k} 2^{m+n+k-2N-1} \\
&+ \sum_{\max(m,n,k-1)\leq N\leq \frac{1}{2}(m+n+k-1)} \binom{N}{m+n+k-2N-1,N-m,N-n-1,N-k} 2^{m+n+k-2N-1}
\end{align}

Probably, there is a way to simplify the last expression.

The closed equation could be computed programmatically faster (and with less memory consumption) than the original recursive function.
The recursion for $a(m,n,k)$ requires $\Theta(m\cdot n \cdot k)$ space and time if Dynamic Programming technique is used.
For the closed formula, we can precompute factorials and then perform iterations over $N$. In this approach the space and time complexity will be $\Theta(n+m+k)$.

**Note:** The performance analysis is not very accurate, since we ignored the time complexity for the arithmetic operations.

Let's just write a simple Python-3 program that computes $a(m,n,k)$ using two different expressions:

```
import functools
import math

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def a(m, n, k):
    if min(m, n, k) < 0:
        return 0

    if m + n + k == 0 or m + n + k == 1:
        return 1

    if m + n == 0 or m + k == 0 or n + k == 0:
        return 0

    return 2*a(m-1, n-1, k-1) + a(m-1, n-1, k) + a(m-1, n, k-1) + a(m, n-1, k-1)


@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def binom4(N, m, n, k):
    m, n, k, r = sorted([m, n, k, N-m-n-k])
    assert m >= 0

    return math.factorial(N) // math.factorial(r) // math.factorial(k) // math.factorial(n) // math.factorial(m)


def a1(m, n, k):
    if min(m, n, k) < 0:
        return 0

    s = 0
    for N in range(max(m, n, k), (m + n + k) // 2 + 1):
        s += binom4(N, N-m, N-n, N-k) * 2**(n+m+k-2*N)

    for N in range(max(m-1, n, k), (m + n + k-1) // 2 + 1):
        s += binom4(N, N-m+1, N-n, N-k) * 2**(n+m+k-2*N-1)

    for N in range(max(m, n-1, k), (m + n + k-1) // 2 + 1):
        s += binom4(N, N-m, N-n+1, N-k) * 2**(n+m+k-2*N-1)

    for N in range(max(m, n, k-1), (m + n + k-1) // 2 + 1):
        s += binom4(N, N-m, N-n, N-k+1) * 2**(n+m+k-2*N-1)

    return s

r = a(100, 200, 210)
r1 = a1(100, 200, 210)

print("recursive equation:", r)
print("closed formula:", r1)
print(r == r1)
```

**Note:** We did not use the the property for symmetry, it can improve the computation, but I do not see where it can simplify the closed expression.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only one equation that relates the four variables $m$, $n$, $k$ and $a(m,n,k)$ the recursion is under-dertermined. This means that there are probably very many solutions - even if we assume that $a(0,0,0)$ is fixed. In order to come up with concrete solutions we can add up to three additional equations that the function $a$ shall satisfy.

For example let's pick
\begin{equation}
a(m-1,n,k) = a(m,n-1,k) =  a(m,n,k-1) = t\cdot a(m,n,k),
\end{equation}
where we leave $t\in\mathbb R$ as an unkown constant. With these the first equation (the original recursion formula) can now be simplified to
\begin{equation}
a(m,n,k) = 2t^3a(m,n,k) + 3t^2a(m,n,k).
\end{equation}
This equation holds in particular if $t$ is chosen as a root of the polynomial $2t^3+3t^2-1$, i.$\,$e. $t=\frac12$ or $t=-1$.
We pick the first choice $t=\frac12$ and use the three chosen equations to derive an explicit solution for $a(m,n,k)$:
\begin{equation}
a(m,n,k) = t^{m+n+k}a(0,0,0) = \left(\frac12\right)^{m+n+k}a(0,0,0).
\end{equation}